# Different types of signature on pdf file

Tags: c#, itext

I sign the pdf files with this code (I use itextsharp):

```
            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser cp = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { cp.ReadCertificate(cert.RawData) };
            IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA-256");
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("testin.pdf");
            FileStream signedPdf = new FileStream("testout.pdf", FileMode.Create);  
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, signedPdf, '\0');
            PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;
            signatureAppearance.Reason = "Sign pdf";
            signatureAppearance.Location = "Location test";
            signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
            MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
            signedPdf.Close();
```

Everything works perfectly and this is what I see when opening the file with Acrobat Reader (*IMG1):
[image: My pdf signed]

Now I'm getting pdf signed by others that display this at the end of page (*IMG2):
[image]

Clicking on the signature opens the properties (*IMG3):
[image]

These properties are a bit different from the previous ones, inserted with my signature, but apart from that, I would like to know why my signature goes in the side panel and instead the one I find in the other files is located at the bottom of the page and is visible immediately.
How can I show my signature on the page as shown in the image (*IMG2)?

Comment: This is a forum with international participants. Thus, you had better switch Acrobat Reader to English before making those screen shots. I can guess what some of those entries mean but maybe I'm guessing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know why my signature goes in the side panel and instead the one I find in the other files is located at the bottom of the page and is visible immediately. How can I show my signature on the page as shown in the image (*IMG2)?

Your signature has no visualization in the document because *you created it as an invisible signature* (firma invisibile)! If you want to create a visible signature, you have to tell iText where that visualization shall go. You do that using the `PdfSignatureAppearance` method `SetVisibleSignature`:

```
PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;
signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(20, 10, 170, 60), 1, "FieldName");
```

Beware, though, the image you show

[image]

with that green tick looks like it probably uses an Adobe Acrobat feature that has already been deprecated in 2003 and forbidden in ETSI TS 102 778-6 and in ISO 32000-2, the display of the signature validation result in the in-document signature visualization.

Such signatures may eventually be considered fishy or even invalid

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! The signature I have reported is from a government agency, I don't know how they apply it.

Comment: Great that it works. *"The signature I have reported is from a government agency"* - nowadays that unfortunately does not mean it's technically valid...